# Unetbootin persistence not working

Tags: unetbootin, persistence

I want to make [this](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/GNURadioLiveDVD) version of Ubuntu persistent on a USB stick, so I used **UnetBootin** which has an option for persistence (I chose 4Go), but when I booted on my Ubuntu Live and created a file, this latter was not anymore present after I rebooted.

Is there a special place where one have to save files on a persistent usb, or is it something else ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "Persistent" option to the menuentries in **/boot/grub/grub.cfg** file

```
menuentry "Persistent" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --- persistent
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
```

Settings may vary a little, but you can copy the settings from the other entries.

If you can't edit that file cause the partition is read-only you can try `sudo mount -o remount,rw /cdrom`